# Are $p \to (q \to r)$ and $p \to (q \wedge r)$ logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

Is $p \to (q \to r)$ logically equivalent to  $p \to (q \wedge r)$?

I simplified each one, I got $\neg\, p \vee(q \vee r)$ and $\neg\, p ∨(\neg\, q \wedge r)$ respectively.

Not sure if my simplification is correct, if not how to simplify it?

How to find out if I can simplify any further?

Your advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Neither simplification is correct.

Comment: You're probably thinking of the fact that $p \to (q \to r)$ is equivalent to $(p \wedge q) \to r$.

Answer (score 9):

They are **not** equivalent.

Let $p=1, q=r=0$

Then $q\wedge r = 0$ and so you got

$$p \rightarrow \left(q\wedge r\right) = 0$$

On the other hand $q\rightarrow r = 1$ and thus

$$p \rightarrow \left(q\rightarrow r\right) = 1 $$

Answer (score 5):

You can try making a truth table, marking out columns for $p$, $q$, $r$, $q \to r$, and $p \to (q \to r)$, then do another one for $p\to(q\wedge r)$. I'm not going to do it for you but it is pretty straightforward. 
I don't understand what laws you used to simplify the expression. One useful one in this case is the equivalence $a\to b$ with $\neg\,a\wedge b$.

Comment: for p → (q → r)                                                   How to simplify p -> (¬q ∧ r)?

Comment: p → (q → r) = p → (¬q ∧ r) = (¬p ∧ ¬q ∧ r)

Comment: Got that but I asked how to simplify: p → (¬q ∧ r)

Comment: I know. I just edited it.

Comment: That means  p → (q ∧ r) is equal to  (¬p v ¬q ∧ r) ?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I've been using disjunction for this whole time when I really mean conjunction. All of the ∧ should be replaced with "ands".

Comment: p → (q → r) = (¬p v ¬q v r) correct? This is what you meant?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12382/discussion-between-eddybob123-and-xijiaopin)

Answer (score 1):

They are not equivalent. Consider the following:

I. If $p$ is prime, then if $q(\neq p)$ is prime, we have $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$.

II. If $p$ is prime, then $q(\neq p)$ is prime and $\operatorname{gcd}(p,q)=1$.

You can easily see that the above two statements are different-the first one is true and the second is false.

Answer (score 0):

The first tells you that IF $p$ is true, AND $q$ is true, then necessarily $r$ is also true. The second tells you that $p$ true implies both $q$ and $r$ are true.  Taking $p$ true, $q$ false, and any value for $r$ satisfies the first but not the second.

So no, they are not equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see this is with the [method of analytic tableaux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_analytic_tableaux). Experience tells one to first check here whether $\{\neg(p\to (q\to r)),\, \neg (p\to(q \vee r))\}$ is satisfiable (since the tableau is nice and small): if $(p\to (q\to r))\leftrightarrow (p\to(q \vee r))$ is true, then certainly $\neg(p\to (q\to r))$ and $\neg (p\to(q \vee r))$ are true at the same time. But we get
$$\neg(p\to (q\to r)) \\
\neg (p\to(q \vee r)) \\
p \\
\neg(q\to r) \\
p \\
\neg(q\vee r) \\
q \\
\neg r \\
\neg q \\
\neg r\,,$$ which is *closed* (i.e. it ends in a contradiction). Hence they are not equivalent.